# Teaching Vector Calculus for a demo

Tags: mathematics, teaching, undergraduate, job

I have applied for a teaching position, and will have to appear for a teaching demonstration. I need to pick a topic from Vector Calculus taught at undergraduate level.

---

**My main concern:** It has been a while since I was in touch with this course, and I cannot decide which topic to choose for a 80-90 minute lecture.

**To people who have experience teaching this subject, can you suggest some topic that is:**

- Interesting enough to keep the audience engaged
- Not too tricky to teach (I don't want to end up being caught in any tricky follow-up question)
- Can be covered nicely in 80-90 minutes
- Has a good intuitive feel to it
- Significant enough to impress the faculty members who will be assessing me

(I already asked this question on the math stackexchange but received no help, so I'm asking here)

Comment: At the risk of sending you to a third stack, this may be a better fit for [MathEducators.SE] (though check their rules before posting). Here, it is likely to be closed as a "content question" and/or as "opinion-based."

Comment: I think the main criterion should be choosing a topic you understand really well yourself. If you try to impress by talking about a difficult subject and then show in response to some curveball question that you don’t quite understand it well yourself, that will likely have the opposite effect from what you intended.

Comment: Why not how the fundamental theorem.of calculus generalizes to the Fundamental Thorem for Line Integrals, Stokes' Thereom and/or Gauss's Divergence theorem? There's tons of interesting things to present in vector calculus, you could find inspiration on YouTube. There are some very insightful channels (that probably deserve to make on-the-spot whiteboard lecturing obsolete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Line Integral**

You can start with Line Integral. Watch some videos like [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-vectors/v/line-integrals-and-vector-fields). Prepare your lecture thoroughly. In a closed room, give your lecture to imaginary audience.

Go through all topics with examples. Topics could be

- Line integrals and vector fields.
- Using line integral to find work.
- Closed line integral in conservative fields.
- Potential functions.

etc.

Alternatively, you can choose **Divergence and Curl.**

Comment: Along the same lines, I would have suggested gradient -- easy to present as a generalization of simple derivatives, and lots of good examples. Divergence/Curl are considerably harder to make intuitive, though this might be a good choice of OP wants to showcase visualization software.